# Using the while loop to ask user their input in JAVA

Tags: java

I have like 3 hours trying to solve this simple problem.  Here is what I am trying to accomplished: Ask the user to enter a number, and then add those numbers. If the users enters five numbers, then I should add five numbers.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

  public class loopingnumbersusingwhile
  {
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
       Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  

        int input;         
        System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter");
        total = kb.nextInt();
        while(input <= kb.nextInt()) 
     {
         input++;

        System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter" + input);
        int input = kb.nextInt();



       }                        




     }       

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code is trying to use `input` for too many purposes: The current number entered, the amount of numbers of entered, and is also trying to use `total` as both the sum of all numbers entered and the amount of numbers to be entered.

You'll want 4 separate variables to track these 4 separate values: how many numbers the user will entered, how many they entered so far, the current number they entered, and the total.

```
int total = 0; // The sum of all the numbers
System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter");
int count = kb.nextInt(); // The amount of numbers that will be entered
for(int entered = 0; entered < count; total++)
{
    int input = kb.nextInt(); // the current number inputted
    total += input; // add that number to the sum
}
System.out.println("Total: " + total); // print out the sum
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after you take how many numbers the user wants to add:

```
int total;
for(int i = 0; i < input; i--)
{
    System.out.println("Type number: " + i);
    int input = kb.nextInt();
    total += input;
}
```

To print this just say:

```
System.out.println(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopingNumbersUsingWhile
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  

    int input=0;

    int total = 0;

    System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter");
    int totalNumberOfInputs = kb.nextInt();

    while(input < totalNumberOfInputs) 
    {
      input++;

      total += kb.nextInt();

    }

    System.out.println("Total: " +total);              

 }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should pay attention to:

- name classes in CamelCase starting with a big letter
- initialize `total`
- don't initialize `input` twice
- show an appropriate operand input request to your user
- take care of your loop condition
- don't use one variable for different purposes

  - which variable should hold your result?
- how to do the actual calculation

**Possible solution:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopingNumbersUsingWhile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter: ");
        int total = kb.nextInt();
        int input = 0;
        int sum = 0;
        while (input < total) {
            input++;

            System.out.println("Enter " + input + ". Operand: ");
            sum += kb.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("The sum is " + sum + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking how many numbers twice.

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
 Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);  

 System.out.println("How Many Numbers You Want To Enter");
 int howMany = kb.nextInt();
 int total = 0;

 for (int i=1; i<=howMany; i++) {
   System.out.println("Enter a number:");
   total += kb.nextInt();
 }

 System.out.println("And the grand total is "+total);
```

}